# Unsupported FS format when integrating subversion with STS (eclipse)

Tags: java, svn

The error below is being displayed when I attempt to import a project into SpringSource STS
from SVN (`Checkout Projects from SVN`):

> Error validating location: "org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: Couldn't 
>   open a repository
>   svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///C:/var/svn/repos'
>   svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
>   svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///C:/var/svn/repos'
>   Unsupported FS format
>   svn: Expected FS format between '1' and '4'; found format '6'

I installed Subclipse - 1.8.x

Version of STS - 2.9.2

Subversion (Collabnet) 1.8.1 was installed prior to installing Subclipse in the IDE.

> C:\var\svn\repos>svn list file:///c:/var/svn/repos
>   first.java
>
> C:\var\svn\repos>svn --version
>   svn, version 1.8.1 (r1503906)
>      compiled Jul 19 2013, 00:29:10 on x86-microsoft-windows5.1.2600

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

You need update Subclipse to 1.10.x that support yours repo version.

In Eclipse menu, go to Help -> Install New Software. 
In "Work with:" insert:
http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x
select Subclipse in the products windows and install it.